# How to write in text file from messagebox

Tags: c#

I have the following code, that write for n times `c[resultwithindex.Index]` and `resultwithindex.result` in message box. Now, I want to write all `c[resultwithindex.Index]` which are in messagebox in text file or array.
BTW, I tried by adding `Genre.Write(sb1.ToString());` which did not work.

Thanks in advance

```
var sb1 = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var resultwithindex in results.Select((r, index) => new { result = r, Index = index }).OrderByDescending(r => r.result).Take(n))
{
   sb1.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}: {1}", c[resultwithindex.Index], resultwithindex.result);
   sb1.AppendLine();
}
MessageBox.Show(sb1.ToString());
```

Comment: It doesn't work because `Genre` is of type `UnknownCustomTypeWeDoNotSee`. To write to file simply `File.WriteAllText(path, sb1.ToString());`

Comment: Thanks  @AdrianoRepetti. it is the genre type   >   StreamWriter Genre = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "N-GENRE.txt"));

Comment: What you mean with _"which did not work"_? It doesn't compile? File isn't created? It's empty? It should work well (well at least when you close the StreamWriter and it flushes its buffer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try : `System.IO.File.WriteAllText("path", sb1.ToString());`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Or, if you want to add data to an existing file, [AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File.AppendAllText(v=vs.110).aspx).